# How do I make dynamic bar colours in KDB with KX Developer?

Tags: kdb

```
t: ([] x: til 4; y: -2 3 -4 5)
fillfn: {?[y > 0;`green;`red]}
.qp.go[1000;500] .qp.bar[t; `x; `y] .qp.s.geom[``fill`sortByValue!(::; fillfn; 0b)]

x y 
----
0 -2
1 3 
2 -4
3 5
```

[image]

Two questions:

1. How do I fix the bars starting at the bottom instead of zero?
2. How do I set the fill to be a green bar for positive and a red bar for negative `y`?

Comment: This isn't native kdb......what product are you using for these displays? You should ask the product owner/support

Comment: @terrylynch thanks for the response! It's this: https://code.kx.com/developer/libraries/grammar-of-graphics-geometries/#qpbar

I'm new to KDB so if I've posed my question wrong, please do let me know! Thanks! :)

Comment: Ok, that's the "KX Developer" product. You might have more luck asking in their official forums: https://community.kx.com/t5/KX-Products/bd-p/kx-products-other

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this turns out to be a different function altogether.

One needs to use a `.qp.interval` chart, setting one coordinate to be zero always.

For me, this looked like:

```
plot: { .qp.go[1500;500] .qp.interval[x; `t; `y; `r] .qp.s.aes[`fill; `pos], .qp.s.scale[`fill; .gg.scale.colour.cat 01b!(`red; `green)]}
```

where `y` is a column of zeroes.

[image]